# ActiveRecord can't retrieve some column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can't figure out why some column can't detect in ActiveRecord.
Please see belows. The thing is `prev_or_next`.

Table definition is here.
[image]

Record information is like this.
[image]

And here's the code.

```
  def script_insert(page, lang, user)
    contents = page[:body].force_encoding("UTF-8").html_safe
    InsertScript.all.each do |is|
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(contents)
      binding.pry
      if eval(is.condition)
        max = doc.css(is.section).count - 1
        num = eval(is.where)
        pos = num ? doc.css(is.section)[num] : doc.css(is.section)[0]
        if pos.present?
          div = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "div", doc
          div.inner_html = is.script
          pos.add_previous_sibling(div) if is[:prev_or_next] == "1"
          pos.add_next_sibling(div) if is[:prev_or_next] == "2"
          contents = doc.to_html
        end
      end
    end
```

**When I see the script like**
if is[:prev_or_next] == "1"

Regrettably is[:prev_or_next] is nil.
Here's degugger breakpoint.

```
[16] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007fa152365f88>>)> is
=> #<InsertScript:0x00007fa1599a1f30
 id: 2,
 title: "関連コンテンツ",
 condition: "true",
 section: "img",
 prev_or_next: nil,
 where: "max",
 script:
  "<script async src=\"//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js\"></script>\r\n<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"\r\n     style=\"display:block\"\r\n     data-ad-format=\"autorelaxed\"\r\n     data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-7141760577373107\"\r\n     data-ad-slot=\"1107433854\"></ins>\r\n<script>\r\n     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});\r\n</script>",
 memo: "",
 activate: "active",
 created_at: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 14:02:50 JST +09:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 01 Feb 2019 14:09:07 JST +09:00>
```

My app is Rails 5.2.2 and Ruby 2.5.0.
Does anyone describe what's going on and how to fix?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `num = eval(is.where)` doesn't give you an error if `is.where` is `"max"`? Also, why does your table show `activate` has value 1, but your debug output shows `activate` has value `"active"`?

Comment: The created/updated times in the output don't match the table, so it's been changed.

Comment: @lurker Thanks. As you said earlier, is.where is 'max'. This time, it's OK. The thing is prev_or_next column. Though this column has '1' or '2', ActiveRecord can't detect the value. Why prev_or_next is nil?

Comment: You need to show the version of the table data that your program is actually handling. That was my main point. Since the table values you are showing clearly are not all the same, it's hard to trust the value of `prev_or_next`. Perhaps its value actually is NULL in the table.

Comment: Thanks. But luckily I solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry finally I get it.
I've examined my model. Here's the problem.

```
class InsertScript < ApplicationRecord
  enum prev_or_next: {"prev": 1, "next": 2}
  enum activate: {"active": true, "non_active": false}

  default_scope { where("activate = true") }
```

This enum definition made some mischief. When I eliminated this, it recovered.

Comment: This is why it's important to show all relevant portions of code in the original question. This part of the code you now show makes all the difference.